# Why do I get this badbox error?

Tags: tables, badness

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
Applied voltage amplitude & Voltage amplitude at clamper diode & Average Voltage using PMMC & DC Voltage using digital multimeter \\
\hline 
20 & 10 & 13 & 23 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I get this error.

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 66--66
Underfull \hbox (badness 4518) in paragraph at lines 66--67
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, you are getting those bad boxes in lines 66 and 6y, you code has just a few lines. Please extend the code to make it compilable for us by copy/paste. This also means seeing your margins (defaults?).

Comment: Are you, by any chance, trying to insert a blank line using `\\\`? Don't.

Answer (score 2):

It can't full-justify lines in the column's `\parbox` because they are too narrow (one word across).  Going raggedright on each column eliminates the underfull boxes.

I also use a `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\` lest the `\\` be interpreted as a macro inside the `\parbox` rather than as part of the `tabular`.

And, as Werner points out, 5 columns were not necessary, so I made it 4 in the `tabular` definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
\raggedright Applied voltage amplitude & \raggedright Voltage amplitude at clamper diode & 
\raggedright Average Voltage using PMMC & \raggedright DC Voltage using digital multimeter 
\tabularnewline
\hline 
20 & 10 & 13 & 23 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You get better results using `makecell`; for technical reasons, I also make the `\makecell` command robust (this avoids additional braces).

I show two versions of the table, one with `booktabs` commands and no vertical rules, the other with boxed cells. I have no doubts that the first one is better.

Rather than guessing a width, it's better to leave the computations to TeX. Consult the documentation of `siunitx` to know how to adjust the argument to `table-format` for the actual data. It allows you to get automatic alignment at the decimal period.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell,booktabs,etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\robustify{\makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{% adjust the column formats for the real data
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
}
\toprule
\makecell{Applied \\ voltage \\ amplitude} &
\makecell{Voltage \\ amplitude at \\ clamper \\ diode} &
\makecell{Average \\ voltage \\ using PMMC} &
\makecell{DC voltage \\ using digital \\ multimeter} \\
\midrule
20 & 10 & 13 & 23 \\
20 & 10 & 13 & 23 \\
20 & 10 & 13 & 23 \\
20 & 10 & 13 & 23 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{% adjust the column formats for the real data
  |S[table-format=2.0]
  |S[table-format=2.0]
  |S[table-format=2.0]
  |S[table-format=2.0]|
}
\hline
\makecell{Applied \\ voltage \\ amplitude} &
\makecell{Voltage \\ amplitude at \\ clamper \\ diode} &
\makecell{Average \\ voltage \\ using PMMC} &
\makecell{DC voltage \\ using digital \\ multimeter} \\
\hline
20 & 10 & 13 & 23 \\
20 & 10 & 13 & 23 \\
20 & 10 & 13 & 23 \\
20 & 10 & 13 & 23 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Don't use the `[H]` option to `table`; you will regret it if you do.

[image]